# MatCheckbox not checking in mobile

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Clicking MatCheckbox on mobile does not check the checkbox. The ripple effect shows, but the checkbox state does not change. Click events are fired. Tabing to the checkbox and hitting space will check the checkbox as expected.

I've been unable to duplicate the issue on stackblitz, but it can be seen on our test site [here](https://test.aryv.com/checkbox-test).

This occurs on Android Chrome and iOS Safari. It also occurs when the page in loaded on desktop chrome with a mobile device set through dev tools (the device must be set before loading the page).

The project is a hybrid with angularjs and angular 7.2. We are creating new components with angular material 7.2, but the MatCheckboxes are not working correctly in mobile view only.

I've tried upgrading to angular/angular material 8.2, but the behavior is the same.